# How can I make related entries and globals part of the search considerations?

Tags: relations, search, globals

How can I make related entries and globals part of the search considerations? 
So I have a website search bar that searches the whole website. 
Within some jobs pages there are some global elements that exist, a related entries to pull through some on page related content (a call out bar) and some general text that is used on all jobs pages. The reason these are global, is that they can be updated and applied to multiple pages in one go.

However, doing a search for the phrase 'benefits' does not include any jobs pages at all, even though the call-out bar and the global benefits content are used on each job page/template.

Equally on other pages, there is a related module type that links to related entries ((call out bars) and I would like these to be part of the search considerations too, so this issue stretches further than just one section.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to guess that Search does work on rendered templates, so relatedTo items and globals would not figure into the results.

Is it possible to add something to the query string? If so, you could modify the search results page with a "related to" query.